# How to extract documents that has 2 or more nested object?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am trying to extract documents that has 2 or more nested objects on Elasticsearch 6.1.2.
our index has such a simple mapping.

```
    {
        "organizations": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "text"
            }
            "name": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
```

and we would like to extract documents that has 2 or more organizations.
like this

```
    {
        "organizations": [
            {
                "id" : "1",
                "name" : "company A"
            },
            {
                "id" : "2",
                "name" : "company B"
            }
        ]
    }
```

some articles says painless script query useful for this case,
so I expected could achieve that with below query

```
    {
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "organizations",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "script": {
                                "script": {
                                    "inline": "doc['organizations'].length > 1",
                                    "lang": "painless"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but Elasticsearch said

```
    {
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "No field found for [organizations] in mapping with types [top]"
        }
    }
```

Can you please give me some ideas of how to achive this?any idea or options welcome.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok finally I found out , we can't query by nested objects count.

cause we have to access `_source` field for count nested objects
but currentlly Elasticsearch doesn't support access `_source` field except update query for performance reason.
hence only one way is retrieve all documents and filter at client ...

Comment: You may also consider storing the count of nested objects explicitly in the ES document. In this case you will be able to use regular `range` query.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev oh I get it ! , we will consider storing count, thank you for ur advice !